# Rails validators: Only show certain messages based on hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For an email attribute, I have two validator helpers like so:

```
validates :email,
  presence: true,
  format: { with: /some_regex/, message: "Bad email error message"}
```

Is there a way to set this up (without using custom validator methods) so if `presence: true` fails, it will not display the `format` message?

I don't want to display a format message when the field is blank...it doesn't present a nice user experience "of course it's a bad format... there's nothing there!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `unless` option and remove the `presence` option.

```
validates :email,
  format: { with: /some_regex/, message: "Bad email error message"},
  unless: "email.nil?"
```

This way, the email will be validated unless the `email` is `nil`

- Learn more about `:if` and `:unless` in the [Rails Validation Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

Alternatively, you can use `allow_blank` which will ensure that the validation only occurs if the field is not blank.

```
validates :email,
  format: { with: /some_regex/, message: "Bad email error message"},
  allow_blank: true
```

Both do pretty much the same thing. The first option, however, is a little more flexible.